# AWS S3: Is there a way to replicate objects from destination to source bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, replication

We have `S3 replication` infrastructure in place to redirect PUTs/GETs to `replica` (`destination`) S3 bucket if `primary` (`source`) is down.
But I'm wondering how to copy objects from `destination` bucket to `source` once primary is restored.

Comment: I found `sync` command, but as per documentation it will sync only the latest version. But how to sync all versions & its metadata.

Comment: You could consider using [Cross-Region Replication - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr.html), which will replicate between buckets.

Comment: @John, We are already using CRR and it is one-way, I'm looking for bi-directional sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Cross-Region Replication - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr.html).

This can also be configured for bi-directional sync:

- Configure CRR for `bucket-1` to replicate to `bucket-2`
- Configure CRR for `bucket-2` to replicate to `bucket-1`

I tested it and it works!

CRR requires that you have Versioning activated in both buckets. This means that if objects are overwritten, then the previous versions of those objects are still retained. You will be charged for storage of *all the versions* of each object. You can delete old versions if desired.

Comment: Is it considered 'to-avoid' practice or stable 'to-go' solution? Why amazon official doc do not mention such capability? Are there any caveats using bi-directional sync?

Comment: It is a supported solution

Implementing Bi-Directional Cross-Region Replication for Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3)

https://wellarchitectedlabs.com/Reliability/200_Bidirectional_Replication_for_S3/README.html